# MySQL Selecting from 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite new to MySQL and I am trying to select from 3 tables. I am not sure the best way to do this so I tried the following query (it worked until I added the second inner join to the 'topics' table):

```
SELECT 
    posts.id AS post_id, 
    topic_id,
    date, 
    text, 
    username AS user,
    users.id AS user_id,
    topics.title AS title
FROM 
    posts 
INNER JOIN 
    users 
ON
    posts.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN
    topics
ON
    topics.id =:topic_id
WHERE 
    topic_id =:topic_id
ORDER BY
    date ASC
```

So is there an easier way to select from 3 tables? Or is what I'm doing ok and I've just made an error somewhere? Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What does "it worked until I added the second inner join" mean? What exactly is "*not working*" any longer? You should describe your *real* problem: what are you trying to achieve, which data do you want to get? Ideally add some sample data and expected ouptut.

Answer (score 0):

Your second JOIN clause had to be fixed. I have to add that if you only plan to use one row from topics table, joining all three tables might be not the most effective approach.

```
SELECT 
    posts.id AS post_id, 
    topic_id,
    date, 
    text, 
    username AS user,
    users.id AS user_id,
    topics.title AS title
FROM 
    posts 
INNER JOIN 
    users 
ON
    posts.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN
    topics
ON
    topics.id =posts.topic_id
WHERE 
    topics.id =:topic_id
ORDER BY
    date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `WHERE` clause.

And I think the last ON clause should not have `:` on its equal operator but simply equal operator `=`.

There it should look like this:

```
SELECT 
  posts.id AS post_id, 
  topic_id,
  date, 
  text, 
  username AS user,
  users.id AS user_id,
  topics.title AS title
FROM 
  posts 
INNER JOIN 
  users 
ON
  posts.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN
  topics
ON
  topics.id = topic_id
ORDER BY
  date ASC
```